# Android - Использование FTP и базы данных MySQL с сайта

Tags: android, mysql, ftp

Здравствуйте. У меня вопрос по программированию на андроид.

1) Подскажите, как можно приложению открыть доступ к FTP серверу на определённом сайте и работать с файлами (создавать, изменять, удалять...)?

2) На моём сайте установлена база данных MySQL. Я прочитал в книге по андроид, что в приложении есть встроенная база данных SQLite. А можно ли в приложении открыть доступ к базе данных на моём сайте? НЕ К ВСТРОЕННОЙ, А НА САЙТЕ.

Буду Вам очень благодарен, если Вы напишите мне програмный код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Завести на ftp учётку для приложения и воспользоваться любым FTP клиентом,  например от [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/)

   Вот, например, заливка файла.

   ```java
   ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(server));
   ftpClient.login(user, password);
   ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(directory);
   ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
   BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
   buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
   ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
   ftpClient.storeFile("test.txt", buffIn);
   buffIn.close();
   ftpClient.logout();
   ftpClient.disconnect();
   ```

   <sub>Взято [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library)</sub>

---

2. Если вы используете "обычный хостинг для сайтов" (то есть не имеете полноценного root доступа к серверу), то скорее всего СУБД снаружи будет недоступна.

   Если у вас полноценный сервер, все равно не стоит открывать наружу порты СУБД. Для доступа к данным из приложения на удаленной БД лучше реализовать какой-то API любым доступным вам способом.

Comment: У меня полноценный сервер. Можете подсказать программный код для входа на базу данных сервера с андроид? Я хочу попробовать.

Comment: Посмотрите тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756230/android-is-jdbc-supported-in-android-devices

Comment: Я бы сказал, что категорически не стоит открывать наружу порты СУБД.

Comment: Ок. Буду пробовать FTP или другие способы.